# Eloquent - Sums of multiple columns in an array

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

If I get sum of a column using `Model::sum('column')` , How can I get sums of multiple column returned in an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sum()` for multiple columns is inefficient because it will trigger multiple queries. Add this to your model:

```
public static function sums($columns){
    $instance = new static;
    $columns = is_array($columns) ? $columns : func_get_args();

    $selects = array_map(function($column){
        return DB::raw('SUM('.$column.') AS '.$column);
    }, $columns);

    return $instance->select($selects)->first();
}
```

Usage:

```
Model::sums(array('column', 'foo', 'bar'));
// or
Model::sums('column', 'foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do

```
$total = Model::sum('column1') + Model::sum('column2') + Model::sum('column3');
```

Edit:

You could just make a function in your Model

```
class Model extends Eloquent {
     public static function getColumn($column_name) {
          return Model::sum($column_name);
     }
}
```

Then in your view you just do

```
$value->getSum('column');
```

Comment: May be I didn't asked for that. I can get values
using 
Model::sum('column1')
Model::sum('column2') and pass them to view.
but if it is possible to get an array of sums so that I can call them in view like $value->column_sum1,$value->column_sum2.... and so on